# Copy const_iterator to std::string to save position

Tags: c++, string, c++11, iterator

Is it legal to make snapshots of const_iterator from the std::string class without invalidating it when performing ++ operations.

For example: 
If want to save the position in a string so I copy the current const_iterator:

```
std::string::const_iterator it = prev;
```

Now my parser continues with prev++. Is it still valid and points to the previous position of prev?

Comment: @alirakiyan Because that won't tell him what's guaranteed to happen. Sure, if it doesn't work, he knows it's useless. But if it does work, he knows nothing -- it may or may not be safe/legal/guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it still valid and points to the previous position of prev?

Yes, as long the `std::string` isn't changed (in ways other than `operator[]` or `at()`) that's legal and the iterator snapshot is still valid.

Comment: You can change the characters in the string via `operator[]` or `at()` without invalidating any iterators.

Comment: @John But the position will stay the same.

Comment: I'm just trying to relax your statement that the iterator remains valid "as long as the string isn't changed."  It remains valid as long as the string isn't changed in ways other than operator[] or at().

Comment: @John THX, adopted.

Comment: The string isn't changed while using any of the iterators to it. So it is guaranteed by the C++ standard to be safe?

Comment: @Gustavo Yes, it is. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules).

Comment: The actual principle is that iterators remain valid as long as the string isn't resized or its capacity (potential size) changed.